# How connect to internet use OS proxy and requests Python?

Tags: python, windows, proxy, request, urllib

The personal computer is on a local network (windows server), and internet traffic goes through a proxy. In AD transparent authorization is configured. Python can`t connect to any website.

In python script i get OS proxy settings. `urllib.request.getproxies()` method help me with this.
But when i send this proxy settings (dictionary) to request, i can`t connect to the google for example. Is look like this

```
session = requests.Session()
proxies= urllib.request.getproxies() 
#proxies = { 
#           "http"  : 'http://localaddress:port', 
#           "https" : 'https://localaddress:port', 
#           "ftp"   : 'http://localaddress:port'
#          }
response = session.get('https://www.google.com/', proxies=proxies)
```

What i must to solve the problem?

Comment: What is host here?
Is it the Proxy server?

Comment: @Ja8zyjits, thanks, i edited the question. I meant the personal computer

Comment: are you able to connect without passing, `proxies`?